# Java. Serialize an object into application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, forms, rest

I have to make call to OpenNMS REST service, but it only accepts PUT with application/x-www-form-urlencoded, what is the way using Java to encode non trivial objects into this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to address getting Java content to application-x-www-form-urlencoded: Java has the [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) which will let you convert a String to the desired format.

To get your data into a useful format to go into the URLEncoder, I recommend a custom method to read the Object and produce the desired String. This is dependent upon the specific call you are trying to make (from a quick review of [OpenNMS ReST](https://www.opennms.org/wiki/ReST), they have many different routes and requirements for data associated)).

If making a large number of these calls I recommend making methods to address each of the API calls on the Object that would internally produce the desired String, encode it, and then return the Encoded content for the call.